# what is equivalent method for fromML in spark version 1.6.3

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm looking for equivalent method for fromML that can be used and available in spark 1.6.1?

Below is information about fromML method it's available under spark 2.0 version but not sure any equivalent or alternate function that I can use in 1.6.1`

["https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/linalg/Vectors.html"](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/linalg/Vectors.html)

Let me know if you need any further details, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Spark 1.x (including 1.6.1) doesn't provide `org.apache.spark.ml.linalg` package so there can be no equivalent.

Comment: thanks for response. Do you think any other function could do similar job.

Comment: @desertnaut thanks for comments - I understand that we have library for org.apache.spark.ml.linalg in 1.6.1 however the method 'fromML' is not available in 1.6.1